# When a function which has one parameter receives np.array

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose there is a function:

```
def test(x):
    return x**2
```

When I give a list of ints to the function, an error is raised:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'
```

But an array of ints instead, the function returns an array of outputs.

How is this possible?

Comment: Please clarify your confusion. There are lots of types which do support only specific operations. For example, why are you not confused that this function works for a float but not for a list?

Comment: "How is this possible" it would help if you explained why this is surprising to you. `np.ndarray` objects and `list` objects are very different. As the error message explained , `list` objects do not support those operations. It's possible because that's how the authors of these data structures wrote them to work...

Comment: `x**2` translates into a method call for `x`.  Lists, floats, and arrays have different methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to understand that operators are functions too:
Writing `a**b` is like writing `pow(a, b)`

Functions can't guess what the expected behavior is when you give them different inputs, so behind the scenes, `pow(a, b)` has different implementations for different inputs (i.e. for two integers, return the first in the power of the second. For an array of integers, return an array where each cell has the corresponding cell in the input array in the power of the second integer)

whoever implemented the numpy array created a `**` implementation for it, but an ordinary list doesn't have a `**` implementation.

If you want to raise a list to a power, use list comprehension:

```
[xi ** 2 for xi in x]
```

You can also write your own class and implement `**` for it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why it would be *impossible*. Although at a very high level Python lists and Numpy arrays may appear to be the same (i.e. a sequence of numbers), they are implemented in different ways. Numpy is particularly known for its array operations (where an operation can be applied to each of an array's elements in one go).

Here's another example where you can see their differences in action:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(np.array(a) * 5)
print(a * 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead for lists:

```
x = [k**2 for k in x]
return x
```

The function you wrote works fine for Numpy array but not for lists.

Use the above line to avoid that error.